# Openvpn client lost internet access

Tags: vpn, openvpn

After installing and connecting my openvpn client on CentOS 7, the client (webserver) looks down for external connections. So I can't reach to the websites from remote connections.

Has anyone ideas to fix this?

xx.xx.0.0 = Server IP range
10.8.0.0 = VPN IP range

route (openvpn disabled)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
xx.xx.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth0
```

route (openvpn client enabled)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.29       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
vpn-srv-name    gateway         255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.29       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.29       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.29       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
xx.xx.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth0
```

client openvpn.conf:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpn-srv-name 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Answer (score 1):

In the openvpn server config, i changed this line:
 push "redirect-gateway def1"

to this:
 push "redirect-private"

Problem was solved and the duplicate gateway was removed, however I couln't connect between the clients. To solve this, I added the line below to the server config:

push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Add `redirect-private` to `openvpn.conf`

Comment: I ran the client again:

    openvpn --redirect-private --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf

Unfortunately the same results.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your openvpn or the config at server side... Then use `up /path/script`, to fix route issues after connection established.
`route del 0.0.0.0 gw 10.8.0.29`

Comment: hmm i cant delete the route: `SIOCDELRT: no such process`